# ColdFusion 2016 stopped rendering website after Mac software update

Tags: apache, coldfusion, macos-mojave, coldfusion-2016

ColdFusion 2016 stopped rendering website files in browser after I updated my Mac software to latest one, Mojave 10.14.1. Instead of seeing the rendered page in the browser I can see  my repository files only.

[image: Directory Listing1 Screen Shot]

[image: Directory Listing2 Screen Shot]

I noticed that some previous settings regarding local server and Apache were removed after update. I did restore missing settings back how they were before and even reinstalled ColdFusion 2016, but still have that problem with rendering websites on the ColdFusion platform.

After running  `/Applications/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/runtime/bin` and `sudo ./wsconfig`, I the get Web Server Configuration Window with content inside

```
 [ localhost ] Apache : /private/etc/apache2.
```

Is there anyone who can help to resolve this issue please?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can see my repository files only"?  What happens when you browse to a `.cfm` file?

Comment: I see code of that file chosen on page

Comment: but if I chose index.cfm, I see blank page

Comment: Can you view the page when you are not using Apache? That should be possible via some port like `:8500`

Comment: I tried and I see blank page only

Comment: "I can see my repository files only". I see all the folders and files that are in my repository. I can click on them.

Comment: Can (have) you run the web server configuration tool? After running it you need to restart Apache.

Comment: can you suggest please how to run  web server configuration tool on mac?

Comment: Just check the docs, [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/web-server-management.html#Usinganexternalwebserver) or [here](https://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/tutorial/coldfusion_2016_installation.cfm) or [here](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/discussion/2468291/)  hopefully those will get you started.

Comment: @Miguel-F After running  /Applications/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/runtime/bin and sudo ./wsconfig , I get Web Server Configuration Window with content inside :                
 [ localhost ] Apache : /private/etc/apache2

Answer (score 1):

Change the directory to

```
 /Application/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/runtime/bin
```

Run

```
sudo ./wsconfig
```

The documentation does not mention sudo, but I am suggesting it to be safe.

Source: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/web-server-management.html

Comment: I normally run "/Applications/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/bin", then "sudo ./coldfusion start" .  and it was ok before software update

Comment: What happens when you `cd /Application/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/runtime`. Also run `sudo ./coldfusion start` and what ever debut it has, put that into your original question.

Comment: .After running  "cd /Applications/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/runtime" and "sudo ./coldfusion start", I get "sudo: ./coldfusion: command not found"

Comment: After running  /Applications/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/runtime/bin and sudo ./wsconfig , I get Web Server Configuration Window with content inside :                
 [ localhost ] Apache : /private/etc/apache2

Comment: I have just installed it . Never used it before.

Comment: I found out that I got Apache and Apache Tomcat/8.5.32 running the same time. two images attached on top.

Comment: You should write how you figured that out and how you fixed it.

Comment: @ James A Mohler. One CF developer helped to test the platform and we discovered that CF server uses Tomcat path instead of Apache one and both of them are running the same time. It was tested using port :8500. Now I need to find out how to switch server to use Apache path to files instead of Tomcat one.

Comment: That should be added as an answer. It is 100% OK on SO to answer you own questions and have that the answer that you accept. I don't want credit for your work.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance. Switching path  from Tomcat to Apache one, that is a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

After testing ColdFusion 2016 platform using port `:8500` I found out that CF server uses Tomcat path (wrong path) instead of Apache one (for Mac virtual directory file: `httpd-vhost.conf`)  and both of them are running at the same time.